# knockout.js: No concat on observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Only starting with knockout.js, but already running into some trouble when trying to make a `computed` method based on 2 different `observableArray`s

Using the documentation on knockout.js' website, I've created the following viewmodel:

```
var Cart = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.Products = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.Products2 = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.Messages = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.TotalAmount = ko.computed(function() {
    var result = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(
      this.Products().concat(this.Products2()),
      function(item) {
        result+=item.AmountIncludingVAT();
      }
    );
    return result;
  });
};
```

Doing this throws an error of `"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'concat'`.

I know there is this function called `arrayPushAll`, but it's a destructive function which would alter the original `observableArray`. (I don't think this is something I want).

Is there any *clean* way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Or do I have to make 2 different calls to `arrayForEach`, one for each array?

Comment: Something else is wrong with your code. Altough the `observableArray` does not have a `concat` method but array does. And with `this.Products()` you are unwrapping the observable and working on the array. So please create a working JSFIddle which shows this error!

Comment: Apart from the accepted answer, the concat function does **NOT** alter the existing array, it returns a new array after performing concatenation. You are discarding the return value which actually contains the merged arrays
_MDN link_: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
this.Products().concat(this.Products2()),
```

to:

```
self.Products().concat(self.Products2()),
```

Inside your TotalAmount ko.computed function.

`this` in the context of your computed refers to the global object rather than the view model. So you need to use the `self` variable that is assigned the correct `this` value earlier.

Working Example - http://jsfiddle.net/55kZp/

Answer (score 6):

`concat` didn't works for me .. I did `push`

```
self.Products.push.apply( 
  self.Products, self.Products2()
);
```

Comment: If you can use spread, this works too

    self.Products.push(...self.Products2())