# Why can not I concat data to observable array in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I am trying to add elements from the server to observable array in knockout.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
function ArticlesViewModel() {
    var self                = this;
    this.listOfReports      = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.loadReports = function() {
        $.get('/router.php', {type: 'getReports'}, function(data){
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++){
                self.listOfReports.push(data[i]);
            }
        }, 'json');
    };

    self.loadReports();
};
```

And it works perfectly. But I know that I can merge two arrays in javascript using [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and as far as I know [concat works in knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221174/knockout-js-no-concat-on-observablearray). So when I try to substitute my for loop with `self.listOfReports().concat(data);` or `self.listOfReports.concat(data);` , nothing appears on the screen.

In the first case there is no error, in the second error tells me that there is no method concat.

So how can I concat the data without my loop. And I would be really happy to hear why my method was not working

Comment: observableArrays do not support the concat method, there's an open issue on this: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/786

Comment: Strange, because I thought that in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19221174/1090562) a person is concating  observable array. So as far as I understood the approach I took (looping and pushing) is the best one?

Comment: I might be wrong then, I always tend to use the loop/push method

Comment: @Tanner It looks like you will learn something new from my question and mostly nemesv's answer :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `observableArray` **does not** support the `concat` method. See the documentation for the officially supported [array manipulation methods](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#manipulating-an-observablearray).

However what you can do is to call `concat` on the underlying array and then reassign this the new concatenated array to your observable:

```
self.listOfReports(self.listOfReports().concat(data));
```

The [linked example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221174/knockout-js-no-concat-on-observablearray) works because the `self.Products().concat(self.Products2())` were used in a loop. If you just write `self.listOfReports().concat(data);` it still concatenates but you just thrown away the result and don't store it anywhere, that is why you need to store it back to your observableArray.

Comment: This is something should be included in KO core also.

Comment: A little more efficient approach is to use the push method like so:
`self.listOfReports.push.apply(self.listOfReports, data)`

Answer (score 0):

another way to concat array in mobx:

```
const arr = [...self.data, ...result.data.data.customers]
self.data.replace(arr)
```