# How do I append to a mapped observable array in Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

How do you add a row to an editable table in Knockout.js?

```
var data = {
    "Lines": [
        {"Entries": [{"Hours": 5.5},{"Hours": 2.50},{"Hours": 3.75}]}, 
        {"Entries": [{"Hours": 5.1},{"Hours": 2.00},{"Hours": 4.75}]},
        {"Entries": [{"Hours": 1.2},{"Hours": 3.00},{"Hours": 2.12}]}
    ]
}
var data1 = {"Entries": [{"Hours": 0},{"Hours": 0},{"Hours": 0}],Total:0};
```

The table displays `self.List()` which is an observableArray mapped to `data.Lines` with `self.List(ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Lines)())`

```
[{"Entries":[{"Hours":"33.5"},{"Hours":2.5},{"Hours":3.75}],"Total":39.75},{"Entries":[{"Hours":5.1},{"Hours":2},{"Hours":4.75}],"Total":11.85},{"Entries":[{"Hours":1.2},{"Hours":3},{"Hours":2.12}],"Total":6.32}]
```

When I click the addRow button I am thinking I need to recompute `self.List()`. I have tried from [why-can-not-i-concat-data-to-observable-array-in-knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930955/why-can-not-i-concat-data-to-observable-array-in-knockout)

```
self.addRow =function(){
    self.List(self.List().concat(data1))
    self.applyTotals();
}
```

`applyTotoals` works fine if I don't add a row.

```
self.applyTotals = function(){
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.List(), function(vm){
        vm.Total = ko.computed(function(){
            var s = 0;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.Entries(), function(entry){
                var p = parseFloat(entry.Hours(), 10);
                if (!isNaN(p)) {
                    s += p;
                }
            });
            return s;
        }, vm);
    });
}
```

but I get `uncaught TypeError:this.Entries is not a function` and the new row won't compute totals. So I have tried

```
self.addRow =function(){
    self.List = ko.computed(function(){
        var orig = self.List();
        var os= ko.toJS(orig);
        os.push(data1)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(os))
        var oa = ko.observableArray([]);
        return oa(ko.mapping.fromJS(os)());            
    })
}
```

How do I modify a mapped observableArrray?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mckennatim/jngesuf2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well @mcktimo you are not effectively using `mapping` plugin . you can make use of `2nd paramter Mapper` in fromJS function and build you viewModel effectively .

**viewModel:**

```
 function model(data) {
     var self = this;
     self.Entries = ko.observableArray();
     self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
         var sum = 0;
         ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Entries(), function (entry) {
             var value = parseFloat(entry.Hours(), 10);
             if (!isNaN(value)) {
                 sum += value;
             }
         });
         return sum;
     });
     ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
 }

 var mapping = { //everything goes through this point
     create: function (options) {
         return new model(options.data);
     }
 }

 function ViewModel() {
     var self = this
     self.List = ko.observableArray([])
     self.LoadData = function (data) {
         ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Lines, mapping, self.List)
     }
     self.LoadData(data);
     self.addRow = function () {
         self.List.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data1, mapping));
     }
 }
 ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), document.getElementById('ko'))
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/nejdqktq/)**

I suggest to take a deeper dive into the mapping **[documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)**